# Objective-c undeclared identifier for CGImageDestinationRef

Tags: objective-c, cgimageref

I have CoreGraphics, QuartzCore and AssetsLibrary frameworks imported. Why would I be getting an undeclared identifier error for CGImageDestinationRef?

Here is how I am declaring it:

```
 CGImageDestinationRef imageDestinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)directoryURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [its defined in the `ImageIO` framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html). Link and import it and you'll be fine.

Also the `kUTTTypeJPEG` constant [is defined in the `MobileCoreServices` framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/Reference/reference.html), so you will need that too.

Comment: You know, I breezed through the docs and saw IO and looked for that. Doh. : D

Comment: :) Common mistake, you would expect CG objects to belong to the `CoreGraphics` framework, but that's not always the case. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: I had to wait to accept the answer, that solved that but now same issue with kUTTypeJPEG - am I missing another framework?